# Django Blog Archive-- Display List of Years and Months that Include Post

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to do something that I thought would be relatively simple, considering Django was built for news sites.  Just want to get an archive list grouped by year/month count on the sidebar of my blog.  Something like

```
2018
 -Mar(3)
 -Feb (2)
 -Jan (6)
```

I've done a lot of searching on here, but seems like it's been a while since anyone was looking to do something like this and everything else is outdated.

I have been able to figure out how to create a monthly archive url/view/tempate and can display a month's posts by going to `blog/2018/03`   here is my blog's views

```
class BlogListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'post_list'
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    template_name = 'post_list.html'

class ArticleMonthArchiveView(MonthArchiveView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    date_field = "posted"
    allow_future = True

def blog_post(request, slug):
    blog_post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)
    context = {'blog_post': blog_post}
    return render(request, 'blog/blog_post.html', context)
```

and my urls (please ignore mix of url and path for now--working on that!)

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', BlogListView.as_view(), name='blog'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', blog_post, name='blog_post'),
    path('<int:year>/<int:month>/',
         ArticleMonthArchiveView.as_view(month_format='%m'),
         name="post_archive_month"),
]
```

I think i will need to create another context field on all of my views in order to do this?  But i don't really know where to start. I know that I could obviously manually create a list of months and loop to try and see if posts match but I can't imagine that is the most efficient way.

Anyone have a fairly obvious solution that i might be missing here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is how I do it. It might look too elaborate for what you're trying to achieve. But this gives a lot of control.

You want to add a 'context_processor' in your blog app to make the list of posts available on all pages.

project/blog/context_processors.py

```
from .models import Post

def posts(request):
    return {
        'all_posts': Post.objects.order_by('posted'),
    }
```

Add this on settings.py in TEMPLATES -> OPTIONS -> context_processors

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            # ...
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'debug':True,
            'context_processors': [
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                # ....
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'project.blog.context_processors.posts', ### ADDED LINE
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Add this to the sidebar of your base template
base.html

```
<div id='site__side'>
    ...
    {% regroup all_posts by posted.year as year_list %}

    <ul>
    {% for year in year_list %}
        <li>{{ year.grouper }}
            {% regroup year.list by posted.month as month_list %}
            <ul>
            {% for month in month_list %}
                <li><a href="{% url 'blog:post_archive_month' year.grouper month.grouper %}">{{ month.list.0.posted|date:'b' }} ({{ month.list|length }})</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    ...
</div>
```

{{ month.list.0.posted|date:'b' }} is there to display month in 3-letter text format

Edit: {{ month.list|length }} for count

Comment: this is phemomenal..thank you.  only one issue i have is the count isn't appearing..any ideas why might be happening?

Comment: Sorry, I made an error. Use {{ month.list|length }} instead of {{ month.list.count }}

Comment: @JohnRogerson, something I didn't want to overwhelm with you when making this work. Once your blog has 1000s of posts, calculating count for each month on each page load will really slow things down. You can make a model MonthPostCount to store the count value on saving a post. This will be much faster. Let me know if you need help with that